# How can I return a cookie in node?

Tags: node.js, cookies

How can I return the cookie value in node? The api documentation for `cookie-parser` says its as simple as:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies)
});
```

Here is my server side code to check for the cookie's value:

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.render('home.html')
});
```

However, `req.cookies` returns undefined for me.

Here's how I set a cookie:

`res.cookie('sid' , session_key).send('Logged in successfully');`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also got to set up the middleware. `app.use(cookieParser())`

Comment: @MinusFour - i do have that in my code, but it's still returning undefined...

Comment: You are doing it before your other `app.func` calls right?

Comment: Yes, correct @MinusFour

Comment: How are you testing this? Through the browser?

Comment: @MinusFour - I updated my question to show where I test. Basically, I do it on the server side. I check for the cookie when the user hits the /home route.